# More efficient use of Python for loops with subsetting of a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, loops

I have the following running through a large number of unique IDs to iterate through and create summary statistics based on the current + prior visits. While this works for a small amount of data, this code can be quite lengthy on the larger set. Is there a faster way of approaching this (without using multiprocessing)?

```
import pandas as pd

d = {
    'id': ['A','B', 'B', 'C'],
    'visit_id': ['asd', 'awd', 'qdw', 'qwb'],
    'value': [-343.68, 343.68, -55.2, 55.2]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

agg_users = pd.DataFrame()

for i in df['id'].unique():
    user_tbl = df.loc[df['id']==i]
    user_tbl.insert(0, 'visit_sequence', range(0, 0 + len(user_tbl)))

    agg_sessions = pd.DataFrame()
    for i in user_tbl['visit_sequence']:
        tmp = user_tbl.loc[user_tbl['visit_sequence'] <= i]
        ses = tmp.loc[user_tbl['visit_sequence'] == i, 'visit_id'].item()

        aggs = {
            'value': ['min', 'max', 'mean']
        }

        tmp2 = tmp.groupby('id').agg(aggs)

        new_columns = [k + '_' + agg for k in aggs.keys() for agg in aggs[k]]
        tmp2.columns = new_columns

        tmp2.reset_index(inplace=True)
        tmp2.insert(1, 'visit_id', ses)

        agg_sessions = pd.concat([agg_sessions, tmp2])

    agg_users = pd.concat([agg_users, agg_sessions])

agg_users
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the output of your code, I think you are looking for expanding-window aggregation; [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.expanding.html).

The following solution is a bit clunky because of a pandas bug in `df.groupby('colname').expanding().agg()` documented in [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/15072).

```
# First, sort by id, then visit_id before grouping by id.
# Pandas groupby preserves the order of rows within each group:
# http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html

df.sort_values(['id', 'visit_id'], inplace=True)

# Calculate expanding-window aggregations for each id
aggmin = df.groupby('id').expanding()['value'].min().to_frame(name='value_min')
aggmax = df.groupby('id').expanding()['value'].max().to_frame(name='value_max')
aggmean = df.groupby('id').expanding()['value'].mean().to_frame(name='value_mean')

# Combine the above aggregations, and drop the extra index level
agged = pd.concat([aggmin, aggmax, aggmean], axis=1).reset_index().drop('level_1', axis=1)

# Bring in the visit ids, which are guaranteed to be in the correct sort order
agged['visit_id'] = df['visit_id']

# Rearrange columns
agged = agged[['id', 'visit_id', 'value_min', 'value_max', 'value_mean']]

agged
  id visit_id  value_min  value_max  value_mean
0  A      asd    -343.68    -343.68     -343.68
1  B      awd     343.68     343.68      343.68
2  B      qdw     -55.20     343.68      144.24
3  C      qwb      55.20      55.20       55.20


# Output of your code:
agg_users
  id visit_id  value_min  value_max  value_mean
0  A      asd    -343.68    -343.68     -343.68
0  B      awd     343.68     343.68      343.68
0  B      qdw     -55.20     343.68      144.24
0  C      qwb      55.20      55.20       55.20
```

Comment: Thank you. I had no idea about `expanding()`. Learn something new everyday.

Comment: Is it possible to add a dictionary to perform `aggs()` or is that a limitation of this approach?

Comment: @yokota, I tried that, but unfortunately ran into the GitHub issue linked in my answer... It seems that support for that kind of "advanced" `expanding().agg()` support will appear in pandas 0.24.

Comment: Ah. Got it. Thanks, @peter-leimbigler. Looking forward to 0.24.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use a groupby and agg:

```
In [11]: res = df.groupby(["id", "visit_id"]).agg({"value": ["min", "max", "mean"]})

In [12]: res
Out[12]:
              value
                min     max    mean
id visit_id
A  asd      -343.68 -343.68 -343.68
B  awd       343.68  343.68  343.68
   qdw       -55.20  -55.20  -55.20
C  qwb        55.20   55.20   55.20
```

To remove the MultiIndex you can set the columns explicitly:

```
In [13]: res.columns = ["value_min", "value_max", "value_mean"]

In [14]: res
Out[14]:
             value_min  value_max  value_mean
id visit_id
A  asd         -343.68    -343.68     -343.68
B  awd          343.68     343.68      343.68
   qdw          -55.20     -55.20      -55.20
C  qwb           55.20      55.20       55.20

In [15]: res.reset_index()
Out[15]:
  id visit_id  value_min  value_max  value_mean
0  A      asd    -343.68    -343.68     -343.68
1  B      awd     343.68     343.68      343.68
2  B      qdw     -55.20     -55.20      -55.20
3  C      qwb      55.20      55.20       55.20
```

gets you the same result.

Comment: Note: You used to be able to do the rename in a single step, but that's deprecated now (FutureWarning).

Comment: This output doesn't quite match the output of @yokota's code. Theirs aggregates min, max, and mean in expanding windows for each id, rather than a straightforward `groupby(['id', 'visit_id'])`.